# How to make Material UI TextField to have same width as content?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jss

Based on docs: looks like material ui can only do fullWidth or fixed width. I would like the width to be same as the content in it. e.g. if its a long url text box I want it to be of the length of the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should control the width of your parent div if you want to make changes to your `textField`,
Here is one example where you are changing the width as you type a `word`. Keep in mind that this is just an example, your logic should be different,

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { width: 20 }
  }

handleChange = () => {
    if(this.state.width === 80){
    return;
    }
    this.setState({ 
    width: this.state.width + 10
  });

}

  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <div style={{width: `${this.state.width}%`}}>
            <TextField name="email" hintText="Email" fullWidth onChange={this.handleChange}/>
          </div>
          <TextField name="pwd" type="password" hintText="Password" />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Try here https://jsfiddle.net/prakashk/14dugwp3/37/#&togetherjs=h6bNchy1iw